# Mac OS X - disable program on startup that is not listed in Accounts' "Login items"

Tags: macos, mac, boot, system-preferences

I have YSoft Safe Q client installed on my Mac OS X 10.10.5. Client starts everytime on startup but I do not want to. Unfortunately it's not available in list of programs inside `System Preferences ->  Accounts -> Login items` so I cannot prevent it.

Is there possibility to disable program start on Mac boot if it's not listed in login items? Thanks!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If it is not in the regular user Login list, then it is most likely in LaunchDaemons.

There are several locations for these, one is for Apple daemons only:
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

The others are to include 3rd party processes,
`/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

You may also need to remove from
`/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Simply remove or zip the process you don't wish to auto-launch & it should be gone at next boot.

Comment: thanks, that helped me, except I needed to delete app's file from `/Librart/LaunchAgents` as well.

Comment: ah, OK - I'd assumed removing the Daemon would prevent the Agent.

Comment: Nice info... Google search just turns up dozens of articles that all say to configure User & Groups. I hoped this would work... I deleted a likely culprit in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`. But the WD My Cloud app is still prompting to open on launch. Any other ideas to try?

Comment: I've no idea, sorry - might be best asking WD.

Comment: Nice idea to 'zip' it! Still in the same place, but non functioning.

Comment: This will remove the login item at the next boot but if you get the notification saying something along the lines of "x has been granted assess to run tasks in the background, open login items...", that's because the notification shows before the login item list is fully updated. The next boot will also prevent the notification(s) from showing.

Answer (score 13):

It's also possible to use the official interface to disable a LaunchDaemon:

```
launchctl disable <service-name>
```

e.g.,

```
launchctl disable gui/501/com.microsoft.OneDriveLauncher
```

will disable Microsoft's OneDrive for the user with UID `501` (the default UID for the user created at install time; run "id" to see what your UID is).

The advantage of this method is that it disables the application for you, but not for other users of the same system, if any.

If you don't know what the service name for your application is, then run `launchctl list`. This shows a list of all the labels, but not the service labels; e.g., in the above example, it would show `com.microsoft.OneDriveLauncher`, but not the `gui/501/` part. You need to add that yourself.

The man page (`man launchctl`) has more details.

Answer (score 0):

Visit these folders. Apple-shift-g from finder.

Find the hidden startups files here.
FILES
~/Library/LaunchAgents

```
 /Library/LaunchAgents         
                               
 /Library/LaunchDaemons     

 /System/Library/LaunchAgents   

 /System/Library/LaunchDaemons
```

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?