# How to stop AppleTV app from opening up after macOS launch?

Tags: macos, appletv, launch-agent

Every time I reboot my mac the AppleTV app is opened up.

[image: AppleTV app]

Inside the app settings there is no way to en- or disable auto-start. I looked for related files under `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, `/Library/LaunchAgents` and `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` but nothing seemed to be related to this app.

How can I stop this app from launching on every system boot?

Comment: Did you check Login Items, in User & Groups prefs? Also, is the app Quit before you shut down/restart? Also check `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac OS X - disable program on startup that is not listed in Accounts' "Login items"](https://superuser.com/questions/969387/mac-os-x-disable-program-on-startup-that-is-not-listed-in-accounts-login-ite)

Comment: @Tetsujin That was it, thank you! Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: Most welcome:) It's probably better if you accept the 'duplicate'. There's no problem in marking questions as dupes, it just means people using different search terms can find a single comprehensive answer.

Comment: I think it's not actually a duplicate. That other question is about disabling programs that do *not* show in the login items whereas my case was about programs that *did* turn out to show there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look is in System Prefs > Users & Groups > Login Items.

If it is not in the regular user Login Items list, then it is most likely in LaunchDaemons.

There are several locations for these, one is for Apple daemons only:
`/System/Library/LaunchDaemons`

The others are to include 3rd party processes,
`/Library/LaunchDaemons` and `~/Library/LaunchDaemons`.

You may also need to remove from
`/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

Simply remove or zip the process you don't wish to auto-launch & it should be gone at next boot.